# How to use pdfcrop to crop multiple files in directory?

Tags: command-line, bash, pdf

I want to use pdfcrop to crop all pdf-files in a folder, but I am completely unfamiliar with bash. What I have so far is:

```
for file in *.pdf; do
   pdfcrop "$file" "${file%.*}_Cropped.pdf";
done
```

The name of the output file should be fine, as this gives the wanted results:

```
for file in *.pdf; do
   echo "${file%.*}_Cropped.pdf";
done
```

But for each file pdfcrop returns **"!!! Error: Link from 'my_correct_input_filename' to 'tmp-pdfcrop-some_more_numbers-img.pdf' failed (Operation not permitted)!"**
My filenames include empty spaces and '. Is that the reason? But it seems to recognize the input filename correctly.

Edit: For using pdfcrop with a single file only, the empty spaces cause trouble as expected, because the file name is interpreted as multiple names.

Comment: Your shell quoting looks correct to me, so I don't think spaces or other special characters in filenames are the issue. Where are the files located? Are they on the same filesystem as your OS, or a different one? What are your Ubuntu and pdfcrop versions?

Comment: Is it possible it is creating tmp file and there is the conflict?

Comment: @steeldriver The files are located in the shared folder of the host and the virtual machine that I use. It is mounted in /media. The ubuntu version is 20.04. The pdfcrop is from texlive-extra-utils 2019.202000218-1.

Comment: @David In an earlier try pdfcrop could not finish and I ended up with files called tmp.. which were pdfs with the cropped content. Maybe pdfcrop first creates a tmp file and then renames it.

Comment: Which was my thought.

Comment: @David What can I do about it? When renaming a file to not include any 'special' characters it works. But I would prefer to not rename everything. Do you have an idea how to circumvent this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> For using pdfcrop with a single file only, the empty spaces cause
> trouble as expected, because the file name is interpreted as multiple
> names.

That is unlikely as you are using a properly quoted parameters in your loop, so no shell word splitting can happen in that case:

```bash
for file in *.pdf; do
   pdfcrop "$file" "${file%.*}_Cropped.pdf";
done
```

**What could it be then?**

Upon inspecting the [source code for `pdfcrop`](https://github.com/ho-tex/pdfcrop/blob/main/pdfcrop.pl), the error you get is defined in:

```perl
if ($symlink_exists) {
    symlink($inputfile, $inputfilesafe)
        or die sprintf "$Error Link from `%s' to `%s' failed (%s)!\n",
                       $inputfile, $inputfilesafe, exterr;
```

Which means that a symbolic-link creation was not successful ... `pdfcrop` creates symbolic-links to original files with unsafe names prior to processing as stated in the comments part of the linked source code:

```perl
# Input files with unsafe file names are linked/copied
# to temporary file with safe file name.
```

The definition of unsafe filenames can be found in this source code line as a **regular expression**:

```perl
elsif (not $inputfile =~ /^[\w\d\.\-\:\/@]+$/) { # /[\s\$~'"#{}%]/
```

i.e. (*remember these are regular expressions e.g. `\w` is a word character and `\d` is a digit and `\s` is a space and `\$` is a literal `$` ... etc*) any of `\w\d\.\-\:\/@` are considered safe ... While any of `\s\$~'"#{}%` are not considered safe in an input filename.

The actual `exterr`(*external error*) will indicate the reason as for example if a file with the same name of the random link name it's trying to create that error will read something like `file exists` ... However, in your case the external error reads `Operation not permitted` which most likely is because the filesystem on which your working directory resides doesn't support symbolic-links ... For example `*FAT*` filesystems don't support symbolic-links ... Therefore, changing your working directory to a filesystem that supports symbolic-links like Ubuntu's `EXT4` should solve this issue.

Comment: I checked the file system with 'mount' which gives me 'type vboxsf' for my folder. Symbolic links in the virtual box shared folder seems to be a problem, indeed. Since I cannot change the type here, I will now copy my files to another folder and crop them there.

Comment: Is there a chance that you found out what is considered an unsafe name in passing, so that I can avoid that in the future?

Comment: @qcabepsilon I updated the answer for that ... Plus, [this](https://lwn.net/Articles/686789/) is a good read on the matter of safe and unsafe filenames in general.